# Output of invoice from number of tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony1

I have the following tables

```
customers

cust_id     cust_name
1           a company
2           a company 2
3           a company 3

tariffs

tariff_id   cost_1     cost_2     cost_3
1           2          0          3
2           1          1          1
3           4          0          0


terminals

term_id     cust_id      term_number     tariff_id
1           1            12345           1
2           1            67890           2
3           2            14324           1
4           3            78788           3

usage

term_ident  usage_type   usage_amount    date
12345       1            20              11/12/2010
67890       2            10              31/12/2010
14324       1            1               01/01/2011
14324       2            5               01/01/2011
78788       1            0               14/01/2011
```

In real life the tables are quite large - there are 5000 customers, 250 tariffs, 500000 terminals and 5 million usage records.

In the terminals table - term_id, cust_id and tariff_id are all foreign keys. There are no foreign keys in the usage table - this is just raw data imported from a csv file.

There could be terminals in the usage table that do not exist in the terminals table - these can be ignored.

What I need to do is produce an invoice per customer on usage. I only want to include usage between 15/12/2010 and 15/01/2011 - this is the billing period. I need to calculate the line items of the invoice for the usage based on its tariff ... for example: take the first record in the usage table - the cost of usage_1 (for term_id 1) would be 90x2=180, this is because term_ident uses tariff_id number 1.

The output should be as follows

```
Customer 2

date         terminal  usage_cost_1  usage_cost_2  usage_cost_3  total cost
01/01/2011   14324     18            0             6             24
```

I am a competent PHP developer - but only a beginner with SQL. What I need some advice on is the most efficient process for producing the invoices - perhaps there is an SQL query that would help me before the processing in PHP starts to calculate the costs - or perhaps the SQL statement could produce the costs too ? Any advice is welcome ....

Edit:

1) There is something currently running this process - its written in C++ and takes around 24 hours to process this ... i do not have access to the source.

2) I am using Doctrine in Symfony - im not sure how helpfuly Doctrine will be as retrieving data as Objects is only going to slow down the process - and I'm not sure if the use of Objects will help too much here ?

Edit @13:54 ->

Had the usage table specified incorrectly ... Sorry !

I have to map the usage_type to a cost on the specific tariff for each terminal ie usage_type of 1 = cost_1 in appropriate tariff ... I guess that makes it slightly more complicated ?

Comment: how do i know that term_ident=12345 uses tariff_id=1? Does it use all tariff_ids from 1 to 5?

Comment: This shouldn't take anywhere near 24 hours..

Comment: @Alp .. sorry .. not very clear in my question - term_ident = term_number in the terminals table - I named them differently as there is no relationship (in MySQL) between them.

Comment: @Nick ... thats exactly what I said .. they replied ... "if you can do it faster, go for it !!"

Comment: With my limited (of basic query / update and delete) sql knowledge - I would be running lots of SQL queries to extract the data and then process it all in PHP - but I am sure there is a more efficient way of getting all the data in (maybe ?) 1/2 queries ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go, should take less than 24 hours ;)

```
SELECT u.date, u.term_ident terminal,
    (ta.cost_1 * u.usage_1) usage_cost_1,
    (ta.cost_2 * u.usage_2) usage_cost_2,
    (ta.cost_3 * u.usage_3) usage_cost_3,
    (usage_cost_1 + usage_cost_2 + usage_cost_3) total_cost
FROM usage u
INNER JOIN terminals te ON te.term_number = u.term_ident
INNER JOIN tariffs ta ON ta.tariff_id = te.tariff_id
INNER JOIN customers c ON c.cust_id = te.cust_id
WHERE u.date BETWEEN '2010-12-15' AND '2011-01-15'
    AND c.cust_id = 2
```

This query is only for the customer with cust_id = 2. If you want a result for the whole dataset, just remove the condition.

## Update

It's not that trivial with your new requirements. You could transform the usage table to the new one you posted before.

To make a decision in SELECT queries you can do something like this. But this is not the result you expect. It could be used to create the transformed new usage table.

```
SELECT u.date, u.term_ident terminal,
    CASE u.usage_type
        WHEN 1 then ta.cost_1 * u.usage_1
        WHEN 2 then ta.cost_2 * u.usage_2
        WHEN 3 THEN ta.cost_3 * u.usage_3
    AS usage_cost
FROM usage u
INNER JOIN terminals te ON te.term_number = u.term_ident
INNER JOIN tariffs ta ON ta.tariff_id = te.tariff_id
INNER JOIN customers c ON c.cust_id = te.cust_id
WHERE u.date BETWEEN '2010-12-15' AND '2011-01-15'
    AND c.cust_id = 2
```

Comment: Thanks ....Maybe my question was not worded too well or explained enough ... I have to produce an invoice for every customer... I guess I would just issue the query above for each customer (obviously changing the WHERE clause) ... and the Dates would be an additional where clause ... WHERE date <# and >#

Comment: Sorry i forgot about the dates. I will update my answer if you tell me the column type of date.

Comment: @Alp .... i made a slight mistake on the usage table setup - very sorry - only spotted it once I tried to run your query ... hope you can update your query to help me ?

Comment: Now, i can't provide a fast solution. See my first approach in the updated answer.

Comment: I will try it and see how fast it is ... I have some test data that i can use ... Thanks for your help @Alp